# Change the WiFi signal Windows automatically connects to

Tags: wireless-networking, hotspot

I have five Xfinity hotspots available. Windows automatically connects to the strongest signal. I don't want Windows to connect to one of them in particular as even though it has the strongest signal, it rarely works.

How can I override the choice made by Windows and force it to connect to a weaker Xfinity signal? I have no router or modem, just the WiFi adapter.

Comment: Do they have different SSIDs?

Comment: No. Different BSSID, channel, MAC.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they have different SSIDs:

1. Open Command prompt as an administrator
2. Type `netsh wlan show profiles` and list the available SSIDs
3. It will say "Profiles on interface (wirelessInterfaceName)"
4. Identify the network you want to always connect to first if it is
   detected
5. Type:

   ```
   netsh wlan set profileorder name="SSIDGoesHere" interface="InterfaceNameInStep3" priority=1
   ```